# NullReferenceException после удаления элементов в CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, исключения

Здравствуйте!

У меня возникла задача удалять те элементы в CheckedListBox, которые "несовместимы" с чекнутым (читать как "Е") элементом. Также есть список типа bool, с помощью которого, собственно, определяется несовместимость выбранного элемента с остальными. Проблема в том, что если я чекаю НЕ первый элемент, то вылетает exception после выполнения кода вот в этом месте `Application.Run(new Form1());`.

Вот код:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private List<List<bool>> array = new List<List<bool>>();
    private List<string> listOfElements = new List<string>() { "первый", "второй", "третий", "четвертый", "пятый" };
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        array.Add(new List<bool>() { false, true, true, true, true });
        array.Add(new List<bool>() { true, false, true, true, true });
        array.Add(new List<bool>() { true, true, false, true, true });
        array.Add(new List<bool>() { true, true, true, false, true });
        array.Add(new List<bool>() { true, true, true, true, false });

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfElements.Count; i++)
        {
            checkedListBox1.Items.Add(listOfElements[i]); 
        }
    }

    private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
        {
            if (index != -1)
            {
                if (array[index][i] == true)
                {
                    checkedListBox1.Items.Remove(listOfElements[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

true - значит очередной элемент несовместим с выбранным.

Когда я проверяю пошагово, все прекрасно удаляется. В чем может быть проблема?

Заранее спасибо.

**Обновлено:**

Текст ошибки со StackTrace:

```
    System.NullReferenceException не обработано
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
       в System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox.CheckedItemCollection.SetCheckedState(Int32 index, CheckState value)
       в System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox.LbnSelChange()
       в System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox.WmReflectCommand(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.WndProc(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox.WndProc(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       в System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ReflectMessageInternal(IntPtr hWnd, Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCommand(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       в System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       в System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseDown(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.WndProc(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox.WndProc(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       в System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       в System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       в System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       в WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.Main() в e:\Курсовая\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Program.cs:строка 19
       в System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       в System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       в Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       в System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       в System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Приведите полный текст ошибки со стек трейсом.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Обновил.

Comment: Попробуйте переписать условия цикла: иди от последнего элемента минус 1 к нулевому.

Answer (score 1):

Вполне возможно, что это происходит из-за того, что вы удаляете элементы в ui потоке.
Попробуйте заменить этот код:

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
        {
            if (index != -1)
            {
                if (array[index][i] == true)
                {
                    //Говорим что это надо будет выполнить потом в общем потоке.
                    Invoke(delegate{checkedListBox1.Items.Remove(listOfElements[i])});
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ошибка 1. Не удается преобразовать лямбда-выражение в тип "System.Delegate", так как он не является типом делегата.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить на делегат, не помню уже, как точно синтаксис будет.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>раз уж вопрос поднят редактированием:</sub>

Внутренний код `СheckedListBox` обращается к чекнутому элементу по индексу уже после вызова `ItemCheck`.

Обработчик `ItemCheck` из вопроса удаляет из списка все элементы, кроме одного. В массиве Items остается один элемент с индексом 0, и попытка использовать тот его индекс, который был на момент клика по контролу, приводит к исключению.

Решение - поставить код из обработчика на выполнение вне `ItemCheck`, через `BeginInvoke`:

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    int index = checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex;

    BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
        {
            if (index != -1)
            {
                if (array[index][i] == true)
                {
                    checkedListBox1.Items.Remove(listOfElements[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }));
}
```

Обычный `Invoke` в этом случае не поможет, т.к. он синхронен, и по сути, ничего не поменяет.